# gcp cli error =(gcloud.logging.write) unrecognized arguments

Tags: bash, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-shell

I am writing logs in gcp logs using below command:

```
gcloud logging write my-test-log '{ "ServiceName": "$Service1", "SubsystemName": "$subsystem1") --payload-type=json
```

it is giving below error:

```
(gcloud.logging.write) unrecognized arguments.
```

Please suggest

Comment: I believe you're missing a `'` at the end of your message. It should be `gcloud logging write my-test-log '{ "ServiceName": "$Service1", "SubsystemName": "$subsystem1"}' --payload-type=json`

Comment: mind the `}` also and not `)`

Comment: i am able to get log entry but shell variable value is not coming it is coming as it is like  $Service1 and $subsystem1 not as defined values. This is my command---> gcloud logging write my-test-log '{ "ServiceName": "$Service1", "SubsystemName": "$subsystem1")' --payload-type=json",please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving that error because you have some syntax errors.

As LundinCast said, the correct command should be:

```
gcloud logging write my-test-log '{ "ServiceName": "$Service1", "SubsystemName": "$subsystem1"}' --payload-type=json
```

You only will receive the following output:

```
Created log entry.
```

Please check the following documentation for further information: [gcloud logging write](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/write)

And you could verify if it works listing your [project's logs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/logs/list):

```
gcloud logging logs list 

NAME
projects/<<PROJECT-ID>>/logs/my-test-log
```

or [reading the log entry](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read):

```
gcloud logging read my-test-log

---
insertId: 1abcd235657fghi
jsonPayload:
  ServiceName: $Service1
  SubsystemName: $subsystem1
logName: projects/<<PROJECT-ID>>/logs/my-test-log
receiveTimestamp: '2020-11-26T21:10:25.757859880Z'
resource:
  labels:
    project_id: <<PROJECT-ID>>
  type: global
timestamp: '2020-11-26T21:10:25.757859880Z'
```

#### Edit 1

I found the problem in my original answer.
To get the value of a variable in a json format it is necessary to add `"'"` so the command should be something like:

```
gcloud logging write --payload-type=json my-test-log '{ "message": "'"$variable"'" , "weather": "partly cloudy"}'
```

Where the content of $variable is `my-variable-content`

```
insertId: 1y7abcdefghijk
jsonPayload:
  message: my-variable-content
  weather: partly cloudy
logName: projects/<<PROJECT-ID>>/logs/my-test-log
receiveTimestamp: '2020-12-04T14:03:45.850928566Z'
resource:
  labels:
    project_id: <<PROJECT-ID>>
  type: global
timestamp: '2020-12-04T14:03:45.850928566Z'
```

Comment: i am able to get log entry but shell variable value is not coming it is coming as it is like  $Service1 and $subsystem1 not as defined values. This is my command---> gcloud logging write my-test-log '{ "ServiceName": "$Service1", "SubsystemName": "$subsystem1")' --payload-type=json",please help me

Comment: @RaviTomar I have edited my original answer, I found what was missing.

Comment: @RaviTomar please let me know if my answer help you, and if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you